# Threshold segmentation in area defined by mask

Tags: python, image-masking, image-thresholding

I am having a problem with segmentation. I have an image (74, 78, 75) and mask (512, 512, 97). I would like to threshold all intensity values in the image above 500, but confine it to the area defined by the mask (pixels with non-zero values).

```
newMask = np.zeros(image.shape)
newMask = np.where(image[np.any(mask != 0)] > 500)
```

The above logical operation returns a tuple, instead of an array. What i am i doing wrong?
Cheers

Comment: Hopefully this will help: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/numpy_images.html

Comment: what about `newMask = np.bitwise_and(mask, image>500)` ?

Comment: Thanks. I managed to solve by cropping the mask to the same dimension as the image. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mask[mask==0] = np.nan
maskedIm = np.ma.masked_where(mask == 0, mask)
```